# How do I return all rows in GraphQL query?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, graphql

Using:
NodeJS , Express, PostgreSQL, GraphQL

I can get results for one row:

```
    oneTopic: {
  type: TopicsType,
  args: {
    id: { type: GraphQLUUID },
  },
  resolve(parentValue, args) {
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id=$1';
    const values = [args.id];

    return db
      .one(query, values)
      .then(res => res)
      .catch(err => err);
  },
}
```

I can't get "all" results for a given table:

```
    allTopics: {
  type: TopicsType,
  args: {
  },
  resolve(parentValue, args) {
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM topics';

    return db
      .any(query, args)
      .then(res => res)
      .catch(err => err);
  },
}
```

I tried .any() for pg-promise but it just returns null values. Am I going about this the wrong way? There seems to be something I'm missing when needing to build queries for selecting and return all items in a given table.

Comment: Method `any` of pg-promise will always resolve with an array of rows from the query. It will never resolve with null values as you stated.

Comment: @vitaly-t maybe I have it setup wrong, as it gives me back, {
  "data": {
    "allTopics": {
      "id": null,
      "title": null,
      "details": null
    }
  }
}

Comment: So you do get your records. Why they contain null values though, that's a separate issue, pending the actual data in the table and the query parameters, if any. I only wanted to help with the pg-promise side of it, as the author, but I don't know anything about the GraphQL side of things.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification on .any(). It returns data when using .one() just fine. I may have the graphql query setup wrong , and .any() does return nulls so I don't think it's an issue with pg-promise like you stated.

Comment: This is a dupe since its the same issue as outlined here: [GraphiQL Returning null Values When Fetching All Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786430/graphiql-returning-null-values-when-fetching-all-records). You need to utilize the `GraphQLList` wrapper type to indicate that the type for the field is a List.

Comment: @DanielRearden Great comment, thank you for letting me know. I've not used GraphQLList and will review that link.